# Does this inequality hold for $r>1$?

Tags: inequality

Does this inequality hold?

> Let $r>1$ and $i<j$ where $i$ and $j$ are positive integers, then $$\frac{1-\big(\frac{1}{r^j}\big)}{r^\frac{j}{2}-\big(\frac{1}{r^j}\big)}<\frac{1-\big(\frac{1}{r^j}\big)}{r^\frac{i}{2}-\big(\frac{1}{r^j}\big)}<\frac{1-\big(\frac{1}{r^i}\big)}{r^\frac{i}{2}-\big(\frac{1}{r^i}\big)}$$

Actually, I get $$\frac{1-\big(\frac{1}{r^j}\big)}{r^\frac{j}{2}-\big(\frac{1}{r^j}\big)}<\frac{1-\big(\frac{1}{r^j}\big)}{r^\frac{i}{2}-\big(\frac{1}{r^j}\big)}$$  but can't understand why $$\frac{1-\big(\frac{1}{r^j}\big)}{r^\frac{i}{2}-\big(\frac{1}{r^j}\big)}<\frac{1-\big(\frac{1}{r^i}\big)}{r^\frac{i}{2}-\big(\frac{1}{r^i}\big)}$$

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: What are $i$ and $j$ ? Positive integers? Just integers?

Comment: These are positive integers. Thanks for reminding me. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second inequality seems to be false in general. Indeed, it is equivalent to

$$\frac{r^j-1}{r^{\frac{i}{2}+j}-1} < \frac{r^i-1}{r^{\frac{3i}{2}}-1} \tag{1}$$

And since both denominators are positive, this is equivalent to

$$
(r^j-1)(r^{\frac{3i}{2}}-1) < (r^i-1)(r^{\frac{i}{2}+j}-1) \tag{2}
$$

Expanding,

$$
r^{j+\frac{3i}{2}}-r^j-r^{\frac{3i}{2}}+1 < r^{j+\frac{3i}{2}}-r^i-r^{\frac{i}{2}+j}+1 \tag{3}
$$

which is equivalent to

$$
-r^j-r^{\frac{3i}{2}} < -r^i-r^{\frac{i}{2}+j}\tag{4}
$$

Or

$$
r^{\frac{i}{2}+j}-r^j < r^{\frac{3i}{2}}-r^i\tag{5}
$$

which is equivalent to

$$
r^j < \frac{r^{\frac{3i}{2}}-r^i}{r^{\frac{i}{2}}-1}=r^i \tag{6}
$$

This is false as $i < j$.

Comment: Actually, I got this inequality [here](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Feconomicslab.tistory.com%2Fattachment%2Fcfile5.uf%40176AA147506C2267090D2E.pdf&ei=GtJSUorjNszhrAeW74D4Dw&usg=AFQjCNHDS8dGRxSFw-LQ8LJ5mb_RizyyYw&bvm=bv.53537100,d.bmk).This is instructor's manual to DEGROOT's Pro. and stat.See page 41, Section 2.5,Solution 3. I couldn't believe that he could be wrong! So I asked here.

Comment: @Sush In fact, it becomes correct if you just change the direction of the inequality.